# Відповідник до слова "ноутбук"

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Ноутбук — переносний персональний комп'ютер, в корпусі якого об'єднані типові компоненти ПК та акумуляторні батареї. Походить від англ. "notebook",що можна перекласти як "записник".

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/noutbuk) пропонують відповідник "нотатник" ("note" - "нотатка"), однак, Словник синонімів Караванського дає такі синоніми до слова "нотатник" - "блокнот" та "записник", тобто нічого, що було б пов'язане із технікою. Набагато краще підходить слово "[наколінець](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/leptop)", яке було запропоноване як відповідник до слова "лептоп" (широкий термін на позначення ноутбуків, нетбуків, смартбуків), однак у цього варіанта не надто багато вподобайок, тому також не впевнений, що це є найкращий, а крім того, як вже було зазначено "лептоп" може стосуватися як ноутбука так і нетбука чи смартбука, а це різні терміни.

Отож, чи є в українській мові відповідник або ж чи можливо утворити слово, яке б стало хорошим відповідником для "ноутбука"?

Comment: `Походить від англ. "notebook",що можна перекласти як "записник".` - не погоджусь. Англійською ноутбук буде notepad, а notebook - це записник.

Comment: Перевіяйте, будь ласка, джерела перед тим як писати подібні коментарі - https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замість слова *ноутбук* (що є цілком нормативним) також можна вживати слово [*комп'ютер* (або його замінники)](/q/268). Хоча слово *ноутбук* позначає різновид комп'ютера, але за фактом це найуживаніший різновид комп'ютера, до якого застосовується слово комп'ютер (планшет, сматрфон тощо рідко на практиці називають комп'ютером, а використання стаціонарних комп'ютерів зменшується порівняно з ноутбуками), крім того, різниця часто несуттєва або очевидна з контексту. Якщо ж різниця суттєва, можна вточнити використанням слів *портативний*, *переносний*, *ноутбук* тощо.

Answer (score 2):

Вільний тлумачний словник - [Новітній онлайновий словник української мови (2013—2018)](http://sum.in.ua/f/noutbuk)

> Ноутбу́к, -а, чол. Персональний портативний комп'ютер, екран якого
>   вбудовано у кришку, що її можна скласти в одну площину із клавіатурою
>   для зручного транспортування.
>
> Етимологія: англійське *notebook* — блокнот, ноутбук; від *note* — запис,
>   *book* — книга.

[Українсько-англійський словник ділової людини 2014 (Є. І. Гороть, О. В. Василенко, Н. В. Єфремова та ін.)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=notebook&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> записник ім. ч. notebook, memorandum book.
>
> ноутбук ім. ч. (портативний комп’ютер) portable computer, notebook.

[Всемережеві англіцизми](https://drive.google.com/drive/shared-with-me) пропонують

> Ноутбук → Нотатник

Comment: Також _ноутбук_: (1) міститься у [«Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/ноутбук); (2) згадуєтсья в інших статтях СУМ-20 ([ват-година](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=247&wordid=138649), [гібернувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=211151&page=630)).